# Heroku problem when trying to download .CSV file into local download folder

Tags: heroku, export-to-csv

I have a requirement to be able to download attendee details from an SQL table into a CSV file.

The code below works perfectly for my local deployment, creating a .csv file in the /app/static directory which the Return statement downloads to my desktop.

When uploaded to Heroku the same code fails on the final line (Return) stating:

```
'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/app/static/users1001.csv'
```

This suggests it has created the file on the server but is looking in the wrong place (an extra '/app'). However, no file has been created anywhere (I've checked using Heroku Run Bash). The code:

```
        name = 'attendees' + str(name)     # name = 1001 in this example
        f = open('%s.csv' % name, 'w')
        out = csv.writer(f)
        out.writerow([ 'Date','Activity No','Activity', 'User No', 'User Name',\
                      'Cost','Received','Update Time'\
                      ])
        for item in Attendees.query.filter_by(club=current_user.club)\
                .order_by(Attendees.activitydate.desc(),Attendees.activityname):
            out.writerow([item.activitydate, item.activitynumber,\
                          item.activityname,item.usernum,\
                          item.username,item.cost,item.received,item.update_time])
        path='static/'+name+'.csv'     # this was necessary for the local deployment
                                       # csv writer send to 'static' by default but 
                                       # send_file needs it stated explicitly
        f.close()
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
```

My question therefore is does anyone know where this file is stored in Heroku such that I can complete the download?

One further wrinkle that I can't explain. If I run this for club 1002 (not 1001), the code works and downloads a file attendees1002.csv (this is a file I created locally and was uploaded to Heroku by GIT). You will see below that this file is actually in /app/static/temp which is really confusing.

```
From Heroku Run Bash:

~/app/static $ dir
1002.csv  clubmanager2020.jpg  code39_barcode.svg  eds.jpg   loading.gif  ratings.csv
bwt.jpg   clubmanager2020.png  dump.csv            eetc.jpg  out.csv      temp
~/app/static $ cd temp
~/app/static/temp $ dir
attendees1002.csv  out.csv  ratings.csv  users1002.csv
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: As a general point, you should not be storing files on the Dyno, as Dynos are effectively reset whenever they restart, which is every 24 hours, and if you have multiple `web` Dynos, they do not share the same filesystem; see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem for more info. If these are only expected to be very short-lived, then you're _probably_ okay, but if they are longer lived, or need to be accessed across different dynos/requests, then you should be using a service like AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some documentation to fix this problem. Heroku does not allow creation of files on the system except in the /tmp directory off the root directory. The problem was fixed by changing:

```
name = 'attendees' + str(name)
```

to

```
../../tmp/name = 'attendees' + str(name)
```

and

```
path='static/'+name+'.csv'
```

to

```
path=name+'.csv'
```